# Why didn't Bane reveal to the public that Bruce Wayne is Batman?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

In *The Dark Knight Rises*, Bane publicly reveals the cover-up of Dent's death and disclosed all the  crimes were made by Harvey Dent. Further, he reveals the role of Commissioner Gordon to cover-up Dent's crime by his letter, at that moment ***why didn't he reveal Bruce Wayne is Batman?*** Instead of that, he helped Bruce by not disclosing the Batman's secret.

Are there any rules in ***League of Shadows*** as not to disclose each other?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In the movie Bane was trying to cause chaos in the city by pitting the rich against the poor. You see those judgements passed for the rich people who lived their life so luxuriously given by Crane. Revealing the fact that Bruce Wayne (who is one of the richest people in the gotham) to be Batman might create the idea that not all rich people are bad and might make Bruce being pictured as a hero in the eyes of Poor who would probably start questioning Bane's ideals and could very well jeopardize Bane's plan.

Comment: I had always wonder this myself. This is the best answer that makes sense. You win.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is probably because in the bid that he can convince the people to go against the law that imposed the 'Dent Act' and realize they have "worshipped a false idol" Two-Face, he re-enforces his plea with the letter that Gordon wrote expressing how the true hero was the Batman:

Here is the speech:

> I present to you as the shining example of justice. You have been supplied with a false idol to stop you from tearing down this corrupt city. Let me tell you the truth about Harvey Dent from the words of Gotham's police commissioner James Gordon. The Batman didn't murder Harvey Dent, he saved my boy then took the blame for Harvey's appalling crime so that I could, to my shame, build a lie around this fallen idol. I praised the mad man who tried to murder my own child but I can no longer live with my lie. It is time to trust the people of Gotham with the truth and it is time for me to resign. And do you accept this man's resignation? Do you accept the resignation of all these liars?! Of all the corrupt?!

Bane cared only to rally Gotham against the system that the lie helped create, I don’t think the letter really showed the extend of Batman's involvement in the conspiracy, he simply saved the family, vanished and the police vilified him. Batman in a sense needed to appear a victim for Bane which is fine for him if it helps to promote his false hope, in fact the Batman returning is part of this hope while knowing Batman/Wayne are broken and forgotten in a pit to watch Gotham be ripped apart - that seemed to me all he cared about.